# Safari ng-mousedown Cursor changes to auto when it should be move

Tags: angularjs, safari, cursor

I have a moveable item in my angular code, whenever the ng-mousemove event is called in Safari the cursor changes to the 'auto' cursor when it should be the 'move' cursor. Whenever the item is moved in Chrome or Firefox the cursor remains the 'move' cursor.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

[Chrome - correct cursor]

[image]

[Safari - Incorrect cursor]

[image]

Comment: Did you try using !important ?

Comment: thanks for replying. I have tried important but it still changes back to the auto (text) cursor

Comment: If you show us some code or a fiddle maybe we can fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

I used a number of other browsers that are built with webkit and they seem to be having a similar issue. This seems to be a bug within webkit browsers